# Binary Search Tree Implementation - Search Function can't find Node (Java)

Tags: java, algorithm, search, tree

I'm implementing a **Binary Search Tree** in `Java`. However, my `search` function doesn't seem to be working properly in the remove function. It always doesn't find `Nodes` inside the tree, whether they are actually in the tree or not. I think my logic is correct with a *comparing node* moving left and right depending on whether the `Node` to search for is larger or smaller, but I may have some issues with when I `return` the values. If adding the Node class or the test of the program would help, I can do that. Any suggestions?

```
public class BinarySearchTree {
    private boolean empty = true;
    private int size = 0;
    private Node root;

    public BinarySearchTree(Node root)
    {
        this.root = root;
    }

    public Node[] search(int value)
    {
        Node parent = null;
        Node currentNode = root;

        Node[] returnList = new Node[2];

        while ( currentNode != null )
        {
            if (currentNode.getValue() == value)
            {
                returnList[0] = parent;
                returnList[1] = currentNode;

                return returnList;
            }
            else if (value < currentNode.getValue())
            {
                parent = currentNode;
                currentNode = currentNode.getLeft();
            }
            else if (value > currentNode.getValue())
            {
                parent = currentNode;
                currentNode = currentNode.getRight();
            }
        }

        return returnList;
    }

    public void add(int value)
    {
        Node comparingNode = root;

        while (true)
        {
            if (comparingNode.getValue() == value)
            {
                System.out.println("Tried to add duplicate value of " + value);
                break;
            }
            if (comparingNode.getLeft() == null && comparingNode.getRight() == null)
            {
                if (value > comparingNode.getValue())
                {
                    comparingNode.setRight(new Node(value));
                }
                if (value < comparingNode.getValue())
                {
                    comparingNode.setLeft(new Node(value));
                }
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                if (value < comparingNode.getValue())
                {
                    if (comparingNode.getLeft() == null)
                    {
                        comparingNode.setLeft(new Node(value));
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        comparingNode = comparingNode.getLeft();
                    }
                }
                if (value > comparingNode.getValue())
                {
                    if (comparingNode.getRight() == null)
                    {
                        comparingNode.setRight(new Node(value));
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        comparingNode = comparingNode.getRight();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void remove(int value)
    {
        Node[] nodesFound = search( value );
        Node parent = nodesFound[0];
        Node child = nodesFound[1];

        boolean fLeft = ( parent.getLeft() == child );

        // child node has no children.
        if (fLeft)
        {
            parent.setLeft(null);
        }
        else
        {
            parent.setRight(null);          
        }

        if( child.getLeft() != null && child.getRight() == null )
        {
            // child node has only left child.
            if( fLeft )
            {
                parent.setLeft(child.getLeft());
            }
            else
            {
                parent.setRight(child.getLeft());
            }
        }
        else if ( child.getRight() != null && child.getLeft() == null )
        {
            // child node has only right child.
            if( fLeft )
            {
                parent.setLeft(child.getRight());
            }
            else
            {
                parent.setRight(child.getRight());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // child node has both children.
            if( child.getRight().getLeft() == null )
            {
                child.getRight().setLeft( child.getLeft() );
                parent.setRight( child.getRight() );
            }
            else
            {
                Node[] returnList = findLeftMost2Children(child.getRight());
                Node leftMostParent = returnList[0];
                Node leftMostChild = returnList[1];

                leftMostParent.setLeft(null);

                leftMostChild.setLeft(child.getLeft());
                leftMostChild.setRight(child.getRight());
                parent.setRight(leftMostChild);
            }
        }
    }

    public Node getRoot()
    {
        return root;
    }

    public void outputTreeInOrder( Node root )
    {
        if( root == null )
            return;

        // Output the left tree.
        if( root.getLeft() != null )
            outputTreeInOrder( root.getLeft() );

        // Output the current node.
        System.out.print( root.getValue() + " " );

        // Output the right tree.
        if( root.getRight() != null )
            outputTreeInOrder( root.getRight() );       
    }

    private Node[] findLeftMost2Children( Node root )
    {
        Node parent = null;
        Node current = root;

        while (current.getLeft() != null)
        {
            parent = current;
            current = current.getLeft();
        }

        Node[] returnList = new Node[2];
        returnList[0] = parent;
        returnList[1] = current;

        return returnList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corrected by code in the question. I realized that I had to set the proper pointers for moving a node when deleting, not just changing the value. You have to actually move the `node` with new `pointers` for it and its `parent`.